# $\sum a=8$, $\sum ab=12$ where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. Find the maximum value of $d$.

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

Let $a,b,c,d$ be four real numbers satisfying $$\sum a:=a+b+c+d=8,$$ $$\sum ab:=ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=12.$$
What is the maximum possible value of $d$?

I tried writing $a+b+c=-d+8$ and $ab+bc+ca=12-(a+b+c)d=d^2-8d+12$ so that the cubic polynomial $$P(t):=t^3+(d-8)t^2+(d^2-8d+12)t-abc$$ has three real (not necessarily distinct) roots. This is equivalent to the fact that the discriminant of $P(t)$ is non-negative, but the discriminant is so complicated and has many terms involving $abc$, which makes it difficult to obtain conditions on $d$.

I believe that this problem is from some olympiad-style contest, so there should be an elementary solution for it. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$12=ab+ac+bc+d(8-d)\leq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}+d(8-d)=\frac{(8-d)^2}{3}+d(8-d).$$
Thus, $$36\leq64-16d+d^2+24d-3d^2$$ or
$$d^2-4d-14\leq0$$ or
$$(d-2)^2\leq18,$$ which gives
$$d\leq2+3\sqrt2.$$
The equality occurs for $a=b=c,$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: Perhaps the OP can end it but I'm afraid I can't. Would you mind finishing your thought? Thank you

Comment: What did you use for $$ab+bc+ac\le \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{3}$$

Comment: It's $3(ab+ac+bc)\leq(a+b+c)^2$ or $3(ab+ac+bc)\leq2(ab+ac+bc)+a^2+b^2+c^2$ or $2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)\geq0$ or $(a-b)^2+(a-c)^2+(b-c)^2\geq0.$